# Environment precedence and ports

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following in my `Dockerfile`:

```
. . .
ENV SSL_PORT=443
. . .
EXPOSE ${SSL_PORT}
. . .
```

And the following in a `docker-compose.override.yml` file calling that image:

```
environment:
  SSL_PORT: $SSL_PORT
ports:
  - "${SSL_PORT}:${SSL_PORT}"
```

If I do that

```
WARNING: The SSL_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.override.yml' is invalid because:
services.ssl.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
```

If I set it in the `.env` file, the container is built.

Is there any way I can set the value of SSL_PORT in `docker-compose.override.yml` AND use that same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two ways to set value of `SSL_PORT` variable into `docker-compose.override.yml`:

**1.** Declaring default environment variables in an environment file named `.env` placed in the folder where the `docker-compose` command is executed.

**2.** Add `SSL_PORT` variable into environment variables when you execute `docker-compose` command. It would be either:

```
SSL_PORT=443 docker-compose -f docker-compose.override.yml up
```

or

```
export SSL_PORT=443
docker-compose -f docker-compose.override.yml up
```